# Please fill in the knowledge gap

Tags: soql

Can anyone explain how this query works? There is no object with the name Contacts (Although it's the plural for Contact).

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = <some account id>
```

The inner query doesn't (in fact shouldn't) work independently.

Please explain how does it work?

PS: I found it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MIs9IAG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this type of query is called "parent-to-child" by Salesforce

Basically this query returns one specific Account (because you are filtering by Account id) with all of the Contacts of this Account

It's called Contacts because thats how relationship name is called (with standard objects it would be most likely always plural name of the child object)

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm) you can find exact documentation extract about this naming convention.. I also recommend you to read other parts of this extract.

Answer (score 1):

This 'Contacts' comes from the child relationship name for the lookup/master details field on the child object. In this case if you go to Contact's `Account Name` field there is a attribute called child relationship name, see the image.

In case of custom objects you can specify the child relationship name, and its refereed as `<ChildRelationshipname>__r` in query or apex.

[image]

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I found some better documentation that describes why the plural version is used, please see this excellent explanation from Salesforce docs:

[Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)